# Storing an object of a class then calling a function in that object

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a class like this (scaled down)

```
class FileAndWriter(object):
    def __init__(self, symbol, start_dt_str):
        self.data = []

        self.fileName = symbol.replace("/", "") + '-' + start_dt_str + '.csv'
        self.file =  open(self.fileName, 'ab')
        self.csvWiter = csv.writer(self.file, delimiter=',') # , quoting=csv. QUOTE_ALL

    def write_rows(self):
        self.csvWiter.writerows(self.data)
        self.file.flush()

    def appendData(dataMsg):       
        try:
            self.data.append(dataMsg)

            if len(self.data) > 100:
                self.write_rows(self.data)
                self.data = []
        except:
            print "appendData error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
```

I have another class that composes that class like this. `update` is a callback function of Observer:

```
class SymbolWriter(Observer):
    def __init__(self, symbol, sd, ed):

        self.writers = {}
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.start_date = sd
        self.end_date = ed

        for single_date in daterange(self.start_date, self.end_date):
            single_date_str = single_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
            faw = FileAndWriter(self.symbol, single_date_str)
            print 'FAW ', single_date_str
            self.writers[single_date_str] = faw

    def update(self, dataMsg):
        try:
            today = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            today_str = today.strftime('%Y%m%d')
            print today_str
            if today_str in self.writers:
                #print 'Writting'
                faw = self.writers[today_str]
                if faw is not None:
                    faw.appendData(dataMsg)
        except:
            print "update error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
```

It excepts on `faw = self.writers[today_str]` with `update error: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>`

How does one store an object in a dictionary and call a member function? Or is there something else I am not noticing?

Comment: It would be nice if you just let the entire exception print out with traceback instead of hiding everything but the exception type like this. How do you even know that line is the one that's failing?

Comment: Meanwhile, can you give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This is both too much code (most of what's here is almost certainly irrelevant to the problem) and too little (it can't be run as-is, and it's not clear what's supposed to be in all of the variables).

Comment: abarnet believe it or not you helped. I did not realize I was cutting off the exception string. Once I realized this and updated the code to show all of it, it gave me the error. I forgot to put self in the function. I am still getting used to the need for this everywhere.

Comment: Unless you think this is a trivial typo-type error and the question should just be closed, you can write and accept your own answer, since you solved the problem.